# Host ASP.Net WebSite - What would be an Ideal Hardware Configuration?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, hardware

I am studying various ASP.Net deployment approaches. In there, I got a basic question. Is there any thumb rule about enviornment definition? What could be called a 'good' setup if I have to support 1000 concurrent users(requests).

I understand that there are many factors like how application is designed etc. But assuming that everything else is great, what configuration should I look for like Which processor, how much RAM etc?

Also how many concurrent users below configuration should be able to support ?
CPU: Dual 3.40 GHz Intel Xeon (Hyper-Threaded)
Memory : 3GB 
OS: Windows Server 2003 SP2

Thanks for thelp

Comment: I would say this should be in serverfault.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I did not know much about ServerFault till yesterday hence put it here. Now that it's resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having been on both sides of the equation (web developer and hardware engineer), my current opinion is that the answer involves both of those sides as well.

Your hardware needs to be not only sufficient for general usage, but it also has to cope with reasonable unexpected peaks and failures - which means that it needs to be redundant, and in excess of your capacity planning.

Your software needs to be designed so its easily redundant - theres no point in speccing a tiered hardware architecture (now or for future planning) if the software is going to require significant amount of changes to handle it.

Your software also needs to be designed so sudden unexpected peaks in resource usage don't happen as a regular occurrence for no external reason (eg marketing campaign).

I know that you say you understand the non-hardware factors, but the real answer to your question is that there is no real way to answer it without knowing the other factors - each situation and circumstance is unique, and requires a unique solution.

However, in an effort to add generalised recommendations, try these:

CPU - choose something with a lot of cache, and individual cache per core as well.  This will do wonders to speed up the system.  I typically go for dual core, dual processor at a minimum (for a total of 4 cores on two seperate physical cpus).  Processor speed ratings don't really matter as much as you think these days.

Memory - fast memory, minimum of 8GB of it.  Use the smallest dimms possible for the server.

Harddisk - SAS 15K RPM at a minimum, RAID 6 for the data partition on one controller, RAID 1 or 6 for the system partition on another controller.  Choose a good quality controller backed by a good support or warranty package - your controller is no good if it dies in 3 years time and you can't get a replacement.

But above all, don't just install the OS and app and let it be, profile the set up as much as possible, don't be afraid of making changes to optimise to the individual setup (within reason).  Move your ASP.Net temporary files to a fast disk (or a ram disk - if they are going to be rebuilt anyway, no matter worrying over losing them).  Move the database to a second server, with a crossover 1GBit link between the two.  Turn off disk maintenance in the OS, turn off services you do not need.

Good luck!